# Proof Regarding Inverse Image of a Function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function, and let $B$ be a subset of $Y$.

> Prove that $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$, and if $f$ is surjective then equality holds. Show by example that equality need not hold if $f$ is not surjective.

Attempt at a solution:

Rewriting $f(f^{-1}(B)) = \{f(t) :t \in f^{-1}(B)\}$ which should be a subset of $B$ if we know that $f(f^{-1}(t) = t$ which I believe only holds for a bijection?

Comment: Think about the definition of $f^{-1}(B)$. It is the elements $t\in X$ with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u\in f(f^-(B))$

Then $\exists b'\in f^-(B)$  such that $f(b')=u$

$ \Rightarrow u=f(b')\in B$

So $f(f^-(B)) \subseteq B$

Let  $f$ be surjective and $b\in B$

Then $\exists a \in f^-(B)$   such that $f(a)=b$

Clearly $b\in f(f^-(B))$   and so $B\subseteq f(f^-(B))$

Thus $f(f^-(B))=B$  when $f$ is surjective.

Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$   and $f(x)=x^2$.

Then $f$ is not surjective.

Let $B=[-1,\infty)$

Then $f^-(B)=\mathbb{R}$  and $f(f^-(B))=[0,\infty) \subsetneq B$

In general if $f:X\to Y$   is not surjective then $\exists y\in Y$ such that it has no pre-image in $X$

Take $B=f(X) \cup \{y\}$

Then this will satisfy the conditions.